# XCode won't use the latest version of my framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build, frameworks

I have a framework which is consumed by a DYLIB, and even though I have updated the framework XCode is still looking at an older version.

I have verified the framework being referred to by XCode is correct, and can use a hex editor to see the version string inside it is correct (.32). I have made a separate test app (that does not use a DYLIB) and I can consume the same framework (in the same location) without any issue.

I can even build my DYLIB fine w/o issue, and can see it is using the latest header files. However at run time I can see it is using an older version of the framework (.31) due to the logging used. I can also look inside the binary of the linked DYLIB and see this old string.

The funny thing is if I rename the framework binary, the DYLIB will still build (the test program will fail to link which is what expected), so it is used an older version somewhere.

I have tried regular Clean, "clean build folder", and also deleting the derived data directory (rm -rf ~/library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*). I've also restarted XCode and my machine, and still getting this problem.

I've also tried deleting the library reference and re-adding it, which didn't help either. I've verified the directory is correct by looking at the build line used by clang.

I can't figure out where the heck XCode is reading the old version of the framework from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check "frameworks search paths" under your target settings, do you see any paths you have not checked? Searching framework across OS returns only one possible reference?

Comment: I figured out the problem right after I made the post by using "opensnoop" to see exactly what directory it was pulling it from. For some reason there was an old copy in another directory in my search path that I wasn't expected. Deleting it fixed the problem.